# Experience with making 2 base templates for site

Tags: angularjs

I understand how to make a basic single page app with ng-view, and routing the templates into the index.html. However, I want to separate the website into the Home section (views: Home, About, Registration, Login), then when the user logs in they go to a dashboard which has its own set of views. The Dashboard (/dashboard/user:id) and Home Section (/, /about, etc.) would have separate base templates.

Would this just be two separate apps altogether with different base templates? Anyone have experience setting something like that up?

Comment: You could have two separate apps which which would share templates, modules, etc. It's not very different from having single app.

Comment: Here is one example of the possible structure: http://jsfiddle.net/rdvxb9Lj/

Comment: Appreciate it! I like the example you gave. Probably going to go with that. Looks solid. Probably simpler to split it up and theres no downside.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about only changing the views you can use the $routeProvider to define your templates, controllers, etc. Have a look at ui-route "Nested States & Views" at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'template/home/home.tpl.html',
    controller: 'LomeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .when('/dashboard/user:id',{
    templateUrl: 'template/dashboard/dashboard.tpl.html',
    controller: 'dashboard',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
```

Another approach you can take it to create a provider to display the template based on user login status.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'loginService'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', 'loginCheckerProvider', function($routeProvider, loginCheckerProvider) {

    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: (loginCheckerProvider.isLoged()) ? 'loggedin.html' : 'loggedout.html'
          //controller: 'aboutCtl',
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  }]);
```

And the provider:

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

    function loginChecker() {
      this.$get = angular.noop;

      //Do your logics to check if user is loggedin and add the result to the return below
      //toggle the return below between true and false
      this.isLoged = function(){
        return true;
      }
    }

    angular.module('loginService',[])
      .provider('loginChecker', loginChecker);

})();
```

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFDMU57CLZFukpA5xUSx?p=preview) to test and it is working. To test it go to loginservice.js file and toggle the return to true/false, you will see the template updating.

Comment: Thanks. I'll sit down and look into UI-router. Looks like you can do alot more with it than the regular $routeProvider

Comment: @ebens9672 I added a solution to make all the paths display a dynamic template. please have a look at the plunker. If you go to loginservice.js file and change toggle the return to true/false you will see the template changing. Hope this will help you